# Regex synta rule for many question marks

Tags: r

Using a code like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    separate_rows(title, status, sep="\\?????") %>%
    spread(title, status)
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

Comment: Use `sep="\\?+"` or `sep= "[?]+"` and if it is exactly 5, `\\?{5}`

Comment: @akrun thank you that's right. Now I receive this error Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows but the are note duplicates. Any suggestion please?

Comment: If you can post the dput of the input example (small data) would be eassier to understsand